# How to sum a column based on unique grouping values in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the below dataset and I'm wanting to create a new column that sums the `duration` column based on unique values for `drill`.

For example, I only want the value `3` for `"Drill 1"` summed once and not for every occurrence. `3`for `Drill 1` should be added to `5` for `Drill 2` and so on. The new column should have the value `32` filled (durations for each unique `drill` added together). What's the best way I can do this in `dplyr`?

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(10)
player <- rep(rep(paste("Player", LETTERS[1:5]), each = 1), times = 5)
date <- rep(seq(as.Date('2023/01/01'), as.Date('2023/01/05'), by = "day"),
            each = 5)
drill <- rep(paste("Drill", 1:5), each = 5)
duration <- rep(c(3, 5, 8, 6, 10), each = 5)

df <- data.frame(player, date, drill, duration)
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps like so? I'm not sure what should happen if there is ever more than one duration per drill, or if it varies by player, etc.?

```
df |>
  left_join(
    df |>
      distinct(drill, duration) |>
      mutate(cuml = cumsum(duration))
  )
```

Result

```
Joining with `by = join_by(drill, duration)`
     player       date   drill duration cuml
1  Player A 2023-01-01 Drill 1        3    3
2  Player B 2023-01-01 Drill 1        3    3
3  Player C 2023-01-01 Drill 1        3    3
4  Player D 2023-01-01 Drill 1        3    3
5  Player E 2023-01-01 Drill 1        3    3
6  Player A 2023-01-02 Drill 2        5    8
7  Player B 2023-01-02 Drill 2        5    8
8  Player C 2023-01-02 Drill 2        5    8
9  Player D 2023-01-02 Drill 2        5    8
10 Player E 2023-01-02 Drill 2        5    8
11 Player A 2023-01-03 Drill 3        8   16
12 Player B 2023-01-03 Drill 3        8   16
13 Player C 2023-01-03 Drill 3        8   16
14 Player D 2023-01-03 Drill 3        8   16
15 Player E 2023-01-03 Drill 3        8   16
16 Player A 2023-01-04 Drill 4        6   22
17 Player B 2023-01-04 Drill 4        6   22
18 Player C 2023-01-04 Drill 4        6   22
19 Player D 2023-01-04 Drill 4        6   22
20 Player E 2023-01-04 Drill 4        6   22
21 Player A 2023-01-05 Drill 5       10   32
22 Player B 2023-01-05 Drill 5       10   32
23 Player C 2023-01-05 Drill 5       10   32
24 Player D 2023-01-05 Drill 5       10   32
25 Player E 2023-01-05 Drill 5       10   32
```